# Including subprojects .pri in another folder

Tags: c++, makefile, project, qt-creator, qmake

I have qt project `proj1` which depends on another (`proj2`).

Directory tree is like this:

```
common/
      `--/pr1/ 
            proj1.pri
            main.cpp
      `--/pr2/
            proj2.pri
            src1.cpp
            src2.cpp
```

proj1 includes proj2:

```
include(../proj2.pri)
```

while in proj2.pri sources are listed as they are in current (pr2) dir:

```
SOURCES += src1.cpp \ 
           src2.cpp
```

So when I try to build `proj1` I'm getting such error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `src1.cpp', needed by `src1.o'.  Stop.
```

Is there any correct way to include subproject's sources (I need to do so for debugging) with help of pri-files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In proj1.pri, before including proj2.pri:

```
PROJECT_ONE_IS_DEFINED = 1
```

In proj2.pri:

```
isEmpty(PROJECT_ONE_IS_DEFINED){ 
    DEPENDPATH += pr2
    INCLUDEPATH += pr2
} !isEmpty(PROJECT_ONE_IS_DEFINED){
    DEPENDPATH += ..\pr2
    INCLUDEPATH += ..\pr2
}
```

This way project 2 will be included normally if used by itself, and will be included properly if used as part of project 1....

Or, you can simply add path to pr2 to DEPENDPATH in project1, as long as path to your cpp files is added to dependpath, make will work fine

### EDIT:

The most efficient way that allows to include .pri file in many projects without worrying about specific path for each case is to add

```
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
```

in the beginning of each .pri file.

Comment: Илья, спасибо, сделал так, как ты в добавке сказал (сразу сам так попробовал, думал отписать, но ты раньше приписал :) .

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Я нашел ещё более эффективный способ - можно просто использовать $$PWD в каждом .pri - я отредактировал ответ, тогда нет нужно прописывать пути если .при включается во много разных проектов.

Comment: У меня ваш способ не работает. Приходится добавлять $$PWD/myitem.cpp перед каждым файлом в .pri проекте. Как в примере Qt'a pathstroke (на страничке welcome)